# Mobile master content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp content in my default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="NewsContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentHolder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MostViewed" ContentPlaceHolderID="SidebarHolder" runat="server" >
</asp:Content>
```

For Site.Master I want to show both
but for Mobile.Master I want to show only #NewsContent

Any suggestions how to do that ???

Comment: Explain it a bit better...

Comment: I edited the question , I hope it is explained better

Comment: You are switching between two different master pages right?  When you detect a mobile device, you switch the master page, but web forms has a requirement that you have the same content placeholders.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are switching between master pages dynamically, so my answer is based off of that assumption.  Because you need the content placeholders to be the exact same for each master page, what you can do is this: In the code-behind, you may (not sure if you can) set the content control to `visible="False"`; otherwise, wrap it in an asp:Panel control and set `Visible="False"` on the panel if the content control can't be hidden.  Visible attribute doesn't render any content to client.